# how to input kwargs into bloomberg wrapper function

Tags: python-3.x, github, keyword-argument, blpapi

I am referring to the following code posted on GitHub which creates a wrapper interface around the blpapi package to replicate Excel functionality of the popular functions: BDP, BDH, and BDS.

https://github.com/691175002/BLPInterface/blob/master/blp.py

for those familiar, I am interested in replicating the result of calling in Excel

=BDS("NHSLTOT Index","ECO_FUTURE_RELEASE_DATE_LIST","START_DT","20140901","END_DT","20170923")

The wrapper equivalent of this function is referred to as bulkRequest - and it works well without the START_DT and END_DT arguments, i.e.

```
blp.bulkRequest("NHSLTOT Index", "ECO_FUTURE_RELEASE_DATE_LIST")
```

returns a DataFrame, but I would like to include the date range as above, which i believe the module provides for via the *kwargs, but I am unable to get this to work correctly. it would seem to me that these should be input as a dictionary, i.e.

```
blp.bulkRequest("NHSLTOT Index", "ECO_FUTURE_RELEASE_DATE_LIST", elements={"START_DT":"20140901","END_DT":"20170923"})
```

but this returns an error. any guidance appreciated

Comment: What's the error you are getting from this?

Comment: NotFoundException: Sub-element '(null)' does not exist

Comment: Including a stack trace of the error would be helpful

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?